# How to get and display value of js object inside property object

Tags: javascript, object

I would need help on js codes. I need to get and display the value on an object inside a property object

[image]

I need to get the values of "Score" and "Value"

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do:

```
 $scope.profileData.FORM[1].line[2].Heading
```

and

```
 $scope.profileData.FORM[1].line[2].Value
```

I would strongly recommend that you replace the `[object,object,object]` by named fields or an explicit array.

Comment: this is noted! this is exactly what i need. thank you!